# mi pagina no aparece en vista previa en whatsapp, facebook, twitter

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, whatsapp

He diseñado una página en angular y todo funciona muy bien, pero al hacer una vista previa no aparece nada en WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter, en este momento estoy haciendo pruebas de socialsharepreview y me sale un error https://socialsharepreview.com/?url=https://yoelijo.com.co/

Aquí está el index.html de mi página

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Yo Elijo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/yoelijo.png">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML Meta Tags -->
<meta name="description" content="Haga click para responder la encuesta">

<!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://yoelijo.com.co/poll/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Responde la Encuesta">
<meta property="og:description" content="Haga click para responder la encuesta">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://yoelijo.com.co/assets/images/yoelijo.png">
<!-- Twitter Meta Tags -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://yoelijo.com.co/poll/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Responde la Encuesta">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Haga click para responder la encuesta">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://yoelijo.com.co/assets/images/yoelijo.png">

</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de la etiqueta **HEAD** de tu html te faltan cabeceras para poder realizar lo que quieres, que salga como una especie de carta cuando compartas por facebook, tweeter, whatsapp, etc...

```
<!-- FACEBOOK Open Graph === -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<!-- <meta property="og:type" content="article" />  PARA ARTÍCULOS  -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descripcion" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Ruta de una imagen"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800" /><!-- Importante -->
<meta property="og:image:height" content="418" /><!-- Importante -->
<meta property="og:url" content="url de la web" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name" /> 

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="330307617951079"/>  

<!-- TWITTER Open Graph === -->
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="title"/> 
<meta name="twitter:description" content="descripcion" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="ruta de una imagen"/> 
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="ruta de una imagen"/> 

<meta property="og:title" content="title"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url de la web" />
<meta property="og:image" content="imagen"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Descripcion." /> 

<meta name ="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="url de la web" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Nombre de la cuenta de twitter">
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda. Donde pongo url de la web quiero decir la url entera, `https://myweb.com/`